# Form entries not appearing

Tags: cognito-forms

I've stumbled across an issue with one of my forms. You see the information from it does not show in the table.

Seems to be the same issue when i try to customize the notification with fields from the form. They are not showing up.

None such issues with my other forms.

Can you please help me out? (pic below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Fields inside of a Repeating Section will not display in the Entry list view, as each field could have many different items in the Repeating Section. You will have to open up each entry in order to view fields inside of a Repeating Section.